# How much water does the Emirates A380 carry in order to provide onboard showers?

Tags: weight-and-balance, airbus-a380

Do you realize that we are living in a world where you can get on an airliner and disembark *cleaner than when you got on*?

[Video: Shower in A380 First Class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJijj-qMx4U&t=5m15s)

This just blows my mind.

**How much water does the Emirates A380 carry in order to provide onboard showers?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to [Pondlife's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/11133/65), I am contributing some more details.

Airbus 380 has room ([see page 250](http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/tech_data/AC/Airbus-AC-A380-20131201.pdf)) for potable water tanks which can be added to existing on-board water capacity for showers etc.

As we know, the showers aren't available for everyone but only for first class, which is probably less than 5% of the total number of passengers, so the water usage is not tremendously huge.

Waster consumption and shower duration is also controlled. [Franke](http://www.franke.com/watersystems/aviation/en/home/customized-products/emirates.html) makes the showers for Emirates and states:

> Low water consumption of less than 5 litres per minute

When [75% of the allowed](http://www.ausbt.com.au/emirates-airbus-a380-first-class-shower-spa-review) shower duration is consumed, it shuts down and you have to turn it on again for the remaining 75 seconds.

Here is a [first hand account](http://www.milevalue.com/emirates-a380-first-class-shower-spa/) (including video) of a passenger enjoying the spa.

Comment: to conclude, 5 minutes at 5 liters per minute per [14 first class seats](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Emirates_Airlines/Emirates_Airlines_Airbus_A380_B.php) makes a required amount of 5*5*14 = 350 liters. Add something to have a spare and for the cleaning in-between-showers. (comment updated with correct figures)

Comment: @Federico Wow. Fourteen people showering once each is equivalent to one person showering daily for two weeks. So each of us uses a third of a ton of water every two weeks just having showers.

Comment: @DavidRicherby assuming everyone makes showers that are 5 minutes long or less.

Comment: @DavidRicherby And assuming that our usual landside showers have a similar water consumption. My flow-through heater has 18 kW and should be able to heat roughly 18 ltr/min, which would make me consume around 180 ltr. (and 3 kWh) on my usual 10-minute shower, which is more than a ton per week. I have heard that others bought a 24 kW heater, since their 18 kW model did not have enough power. That was a real WTF moment...

Answer (score 12):

570 litres, [apparently](http://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/water-usage-on-emirates-a380-showers-much-lower-than-318814/):

> To cater for the showers, the airline's 489-seat A380s are fitted with
>   two optional auxiliary potable water tanks installed in the centre
>   wingbox, which increases capacity from the standard 1,700 litres
>   (450USgal) capacity in six tanks to 2,270 litres - ie around 2.3t.

That's assuming that the 570 litre increase is entirely allocated to the showers, which may not be literally true.