# Did/do any commercial passenger aircraft have showers for passenger's use?

Tags: aircraft-design

The [Emirates A380 has a shower unit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJijj-qMx4U&t=5m15s) for use by First class passengers ([previously discussed here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11132/how-much-water-does-the-emirates-a380-carry-in-order-to-provide-onboard-showers)), but it got me thinking about the many passenger comforts present in [the "golden age" of aviation](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-3659743/Endless-legroom-smoking-lounges-polite-chatter-Nostalgic-photos-golden-age-flying-reveals-glamorous-journeys-1950s.html) (pre-US airline industry deregulation, especially when piano lounges were a thing in 747 aircraft) - did *any other* commercial passenger aircraft (jets or otherwise) have onboard showers for the benefit of passengers?

If not, it seems surprising, because a toilet room could easily be converted to a wet-room shower unit - and aircraft have a ready supply of potable water. Showers could be time-limited to a few minutes - enough to freshen-up after a long-haul flight and I can see it would be popular with business travelers who might not have the luxury of time to use their airlines' business class lounge's showers.

Comment: Personally I think the limitations on water use due to supply and the difficulties of showering in anything but smooth air make the prospect unappealing. Just trying to whiz while standing up can be a huge challenge on an airplane at times.

Comment: I highly recommend we not to abuse the word "aircraft" in this SE. If you mean airplane, say airplane.

Comment: Good point @user3528438, I'm sure Zeppelins had showers.

Comment: I wonder if this would comply with safety rules like when crossing a turbulence area and everyone should be seated, specially with bare feet on slippery material.

Comment: @mins: Bare feet on slippery material shouldn't be a problem if you have good shower mats.

Comment: @GdD: Yes, [at least one of them did](http://www.airships.net/hindenburg/interiors/).

Answer (score 3):

If you're including lighter-than-air aircraft, the [LZ 129 *Hindenburg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ_129_Hindenburg) [had showers](http://www.airships.net/hindenburg/interiors/):

> B Deck on Hindenburg, located directly below A Deck, contained the ship’s kitchen, passenger toilet **and shower facilities**, the crew and officers’ mess, and a cabin occupied by Chief Steward Heinrich Kubis (containing a door to the keel corridor, which was the only connection between passenger and crew spaces).

My emphasis.

Answer (score 2):

On Emirates or Etihad long haul flights, they do have showers available only to certain passengers. [Here](https://www.ausbt.com.au/etihad-airways-airbus-a380-first-class-shower-suite-review) you can find a link to an article about the showers. After those two airlines, as for inflight showers go, I do not know of any other inflight showers. 
The 777 has inflight showers as well. The airline can request the systems necessary to have the showers. So technically any plane can have it.

Comment: The A380 was noted in the OP. The question was looking for _any other_ airplane that had in-flight shower facilities.